# Why should boundary maps be degree 0 in Khovanov Homology?

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

In Bar-Natan's *On Khovanov's categorification of the Jones polynomial* (https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0201043), the claim in section 3.2 when constructing the differential $d_\xi$ is that $d_\xi$ ought to be degree $0$ "so as not to undermine Theorem 1," but Theorem 1 doesn't depend in any way on the maps $d_\xi$. Why should these $d_\xi$ be of degree $0$?

This is important because if we want $d_\xi$ to be obtained from a Frobenius algebra structure on $V$, having a degree $0$ differential gives us an essentially unique choice of multiplication and comultiplication; without this restriction, many Frobenius algebra  structures are possible.

Comment: As mentioned earlier in the paper, we want this so we can consider the alternating sum of the graded *chain* groups instead of the alternating sum of the graded *homology* groups (this is in the paragraph before theorem 1). We want this because the geometry is happening at the level of chain groups (that's where the "knot diagrams" live)

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen hmm okay I see this paragraph now. As far as I know the fact that the alternating sum of cochain ranks = alternating sum of cohomology ranks is a completely general fact that only requires the cochain modules to be finite rank and torsion free (and that there's finitely many of them); I don't see why the degree of the differential should affect this.

Comment: You're right that they're equivalent for the *usual* Euler Characteristic (which is concerned with a one dimensional complex), but we are considering the *graded* Euler Characteristic. Recall we actually have a bicomplex: each chain group $C^{i, j}$ has a homological dimension and a quantum dimension. The key is that if the differential preserves grading then the two concepts line up: a differential on the vertically summed  chain groups (the "classical differential") splits into a bicomplex differential and vice versa. Additionally, preserving grading makes calculation easier, since...

Comment: ... $C^{*, j}$ is now a one-dimensional chain complex for each fixed $j$ which acts simply by moving to the right. I'll agree with you that one could probably build a variation of Khovanov Homology where the $j$ maps are diagonal, akin to pages of a spectral sequence as opposed to the Khovanov bicomplex... I've seen some variations on Khovanov Homology by modifying the Frobenius algebra slightly, and I would imagine these constructions are related. In any case, you want a fixed degree for your differential, and the most natural choice is degree zero (yielding a bicomplex differential).

Comment: The importance of having $C^{*, j} $ be a one dimnesional chain complex is that we can then calculate its (standard) Euler Characteristic as the alternating sum of its chain groups using the general theorem you stated, which allows us to easily define the quantum Euler characteristic by vertically summing the Euler Characteristic of each horizontal complex (we also need to add a factor of $q^i$ to account for the quantum grading, which allows us to differentiate the Euler characteristics after summing them. Think of it somewhat like an indexing tool for which horizontal complex goes where)

Comment: ***Tldr***: we want to preserve grading since we want an induced bicomplex since we want to define quantum Euler Characteristic as alternating sum of horizontal Euler characteristics so we can use the equivalence of alternating sums over homology vs chain groups so we can exploit the geometric structure of knot diagrams.

Comment: I know Kauffman's paper has some of the details on this. I have some summary papers and slides going through the details as well that I wrote years ago, though I don't remember all the sources off the top of my head. If you have further questions I could try to dig them up though.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen this does help, reading Kauffman's paper now. can't say I fully get it yet but it's a satisfying enough answer. if you were to copy and paste it into an answer below I'd accept it. probably my confusion stems from the fact that Bar-Natan's paper mostly ignores the bigrading.

Comment: I dug up my old talk notes on Bar Natan and Kauffmans papers so I could check the calculation. Start with family of $\mathbb Z$-modules $V_{n,k}$, and let $V_n = \oplus_k V_{n,k}$ with a differential $\partial V_n \to  V_{n+1}$. We want a result of the form: $$\chi_q = \sum_n (-1)^n \text{ q-dim } V_n \stackrel{?}= \sum_n (-1)^n \text{ q-dim } H(V_n)$$ Indeed,
$$\sum_n (-1)^n \text{ q-dim } V_n = \sum_n(-1)^n \sum_k q^k \dim V_{n,k} = \sum_k q^k \sum_n(-1)^n \dim V_{n,k} =\sum_k q^k \chi (V_{*,k})$$

Comment: $$\sum_n (-1)^n \text{ q-dim } H(V_n) = \sum_n(-1)^n \sum_k q^k \dim H(V_{n,k}) = \sum_k q^k \sum_n(-1)^n \dim H(V_{n,k}) =\sum_k q^k \chi (H(V_{*,k}))$$
where $H$ denotes taking the (co)homology of the complex (i.e. the induced functor). We now want to use the equivalence of definition of classical Euler characteristic to show the last statement of the two lines are equal, but that requires $V_{*,k}$ to be a chain complex. Since all we have is a differential $\partial V_n \to V_{n+1}$, what we can do is require this differential to preserve gradings, e.g. $\partial V_{n,k} \to V_{n+1,k}$.

Comment: This is very clear, thank you.